# How to present letter as a bitmap?

Tags: objective-c, bit, letters

I know how to present number as a bitmap, for instance:

`17 = 010001`
`11 = 001011`

This is about numbers, but what about letters? Is there a way to do this? For example:

`w = ??`
`[ = ??`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Everything* on your computer is represented as a sequence a bits, what you are calling a “bitmap”. So the answer to your question is yes, characters have a binary representation, along with integers, floating-point numbers, machine instructions etc.

Different languages use different binary encodings for characters, Objective-C uses Unicode. See the section *Understanding Characters* in the [`NSString` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You might as well jump in at the deep end and visit www.unicode.org.

Letters are complicated. And anyway, representing them as a bitmap is a bit pointless, isn't it?